# Converting multiple configuration routes in react-router's plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to achieve something like the following router structure in plain route objects.

```
const Demo = () => (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="fade" component={FadeDemo}>
        <IndexRoute component={Lorem} />
        <Route path="demo-1" component={Lorem} />
        <Route path="demo-2" component={Lorem} />
        <Route path="demo-3" component={Lorem} />
      </Route>
```

My app router looks like this:

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [
    CounterRoute(store)
  ]
})
```

So I want to add the FadeDemo transition container from the former JSX as a route without a path on my latter example. Is that possible?

EDIT:
 That's my updated route index file, now I get can't match the '/counter' location:

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout/CoreLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import CounterRoute from './Counter'
import TransitionWrapper from './TransitionWrapper'

export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [{
    //path: 'fade',
    component: TransitionWrapper,
    childRoutes: [
      CounterRoute(store)
      ]
  }]
})
```

counter app index:

```
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers'

export default (store) => ({
  path: 'counter',
  /*  Async getComponent is only invoked when route matches   */
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    /*  Webpack - use 'require.ensure' to create a split point
        and embed an async module loader (jsonp) when bundling   */
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      /*  Webpack - use require callback to define
          dependencies for bundling   */
      const Counter = require('./containers/CounterContainer').default
      const reducer = require('./modules/counter').default

      /*  Add the reducer to the store on key 'counter'  */
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'counter', reducer })

      /*  Return getComponent   */
      cb(null, Counter)

    /* Webpack named bundle   */
    }, 'counter')
  }
})
```

TransitionWrapper

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

import { RouteTransition } from 'react-router-transition'

const TransitionWrapper = (props) => (
  <div>
    <RouteTransition
      component={"div"}
      className="transition-wrapper"
      pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
      {...props.preset}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </RouteTransition>
  </div>
)

export default TransitionWrapper
```

Comment: Also, provide please `<TransitionWrapper>` code

Comment: I added it to the edit

Comment: You can also check: https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition/blob/master/src/RouteTransition.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes) is described how you can achieve it.

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      component: FadeDemo,
      childRoutes: [
        {
          path: 'demo-1',
          component: Lorem
        },
        {
          path: 'demo-2',
          component: Lorem
        }
        // ...
      ]
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't need a path for the transition component, is that possible?

Comment: Try to remove `path: 'fade'` in that case.

Comment: Not working I'm getting a location error, the following docs are a bit enigmatic: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route

Comment: This route fails: /fade/demo-1 ?

Comment: yes, it gives a can't match location error, I'm updating the question with more details.

Comment: The question has drifted from it's title, I'm selecting your correct answer and opening a new question. Thanks for the help Sasha.